# Google Workspace fileds in Moodle

Tags: php, google-api, google-workspace

I build a simple Moodle LMS, I add Google Auth for login, only user in my Google Workspace can login in this site and it work fine. Every user have a field "Type of Employee" but the problem is in moodle, I can't map this field in my moodle. I found the Google Auth menu to map the data but I don't know the name of filed who contain type of employee data.
Are there any way to get this data in my Moodle?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the plugin, but most authentication plugins have an option for "field mapping" or "data mapping"

https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Managing_authentication#Profile_fields_data_mapping_and_locking

1. First create a user profile field via  Site administration > Users > User profile fields

eg: Text input and the short name `emptype`

2. Then go to your plugin settings via Site admin > Plugins > Authentication > and I'll use LDAP Server settings as an example
3. There is an option to map the data for the custom field `emptype` like this:

[image: Screenshot of the data mapping for the custom field emptype]

4. If the authentication plugin doesn't have the option to map fields, then the code will need to be modified

Comment: Yeah, I know this, but I don't found the metadata name for "Type of Employee" on GWorkspace

Comment: Okay, so not related to Moodle